# How not to create multiple IF with multiple different variables - Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, drag-and-drop, draggable

[image]

This is a Drag and Drop function so the user leaves the items in the correct fields a victory message should appear and disable a button. Even if the user completes the 5 options as wrong, the button should also be disabled but a "game over" message should appear. Is there any more way to validate when it's easy instead of having to create an IF for every wrong drag.

```
function buttonDisabled(){
    // TRUE
    if( $('#items-10').has('#item-1').length == 1 && $('#items-7').has('#item-2').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-6').has('#item-3').length == 1 && $('#items-9').has('#item-4').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-8').has('#item-5').length == 1 )
     {$('#next').prop("disabled", false);}
  // False
  if( $('#items-10').has('#item-2').length == 1 && $('#items-7').has('#item-1').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-6').has('#item-3').length == 1 && $('#items-9').has('#item-4').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-8').has('#item-5').length == 1 )
    { $('#next').prop("disabled", false);}
  if( $('#items-10').has('#item-3').length == 1 && $('#items-7').has('#item-2').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-6').has('#item-1').length == 1 && $('#items-9').has('#item-4').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-8').has('#item-5').length == 1 )
    { $('#next').prop("disabled", false);}
  if( $('#items-10').has('#item-4').length == 1 && $('#items-7').has('#item-2').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-6').has('#item-3').length == 1 && $('#items-9').has('#item-1').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-8').has('#item-5').length == 1 )
    { $('#next').prop("disabled", false);}
  if( $('#items-10').has('#item-5').length == 1 && $('#items-7').has('#item-2').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-6').has('#item-3').length == 1 && $('#items-9').has('#item-4').length == 1 &&
      $('#items-8').has('#item-1').length == 1 )
    { $('#next').prop("disabled", false);}
}
```

Comment: Put the winning situation in an array, eg: `[[10, 1], [7,2], [6, 3] ... ]`. Then, depending on the exact use case, you could build an array from the state of the HTML as the user plays to count how many winning matches they have made. If you need more specific help than this, then we would need to see all relevant code in a working example, along with details of valid/invalid cases.

Comment: Similar to above: separate your game data from your HTML/DOM.  Changes to DOM -> changes to game data.  Code checks game data.